# How to open xls file in iPad which contain macro (Pragmatically).?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5

I want open xls file in iPad which contain macro. This macro are security related and this are enabled xls file. If I try for opening that file using UIWebview then it shows encrypted data error. If macro are disable in excel file then it show all data from excel file.
I also try UIDocumentInteractionController but issue not fix.

How can i do it any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe you will get this in iOS UIWebView. Because when you open up MS Office files, iOS does not let you edit or manipulate these files. So, this is not going to be possible.

You can not use UIWebView directly to achieve this.

Check this app [Office2 for IPad and iPhone](http://www.bytesquared.com/)
http://www.bytesquared.com/